# Passing path of an application in command line arguments

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

In my application, I am passing some command line arguments to schedule a task.
str is a string which after some operations becomes

```
/create /tn StartIE /tr "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe http://abc.com" /sc onlogon
```

And then I start a process as:

```
ProcessStartInfo ps = ProcessStartInfo("schtasks");
ps.Arguments = str;
Process.Start(ps);
```

When I look into the task scheudler for the scheduled tasks, I get Action of schedules task as:

```
C:\Program
and the Arguments as: Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe http://abc.com
```

So, the problem is because of the space in Program Files. How should I correct thing thing, so that the actual program remains
`C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe http://abc.com`
and `Arguments = http://abc.com`
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to pass your quotes in escaped so they can be 'extracted' by the `schtasks` process. Your string should end up containing:

`/create /tn StartIE /tr "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe http://abc.com" /sc onlogon`

But I suspect it actually contains:

`/create /tn StartIE /tr C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe http://abc.com /sc onlogon`

Which means when you create it you should be targetting:

`/create /tn StartIE /tr \""C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe http://abc.com\"" /sc onlogon`

A similar question and answer: [Why "schtasks" does not run my job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845030/why-schtasks-does-not-run-my-job)