# Task Scheduler: WPF/C# run failing with error (though works when launching .exe on its own)

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

Fellow coders,
I've built a WPF/ C# application (with .net 4), the app runs fine if debugging or even launching the ".exe" on its own, the app itself runs with **Administrator privileges**. While running with Administrator privileges I made it add itself as a Task in the "Task Scheduler".
I've made sure the "Run with highest privileges" was checked while creating the task (and verified in the **Task Scheduler** that everything was set like it was supposed to)

When running the task, the task fails and I see this error:
Task Scheduler failed to launch action **"MYPATH\MyClient.Common.dll"** in instance "{8df36ee7-0db9-4807-9b5d-d43a793f2169}" of task "\MyClient". Additional Data: **Error Value: 2147942593**.

I don't understand where this is coming from specially that the MyClient.Common.dll has nothing special; just some logging stuff and a few helpers.
Here are the dlls MyClient.Common.dll is referencing:

- Microsoft.CSharp
- System
- System.Core
- System.Data
- System.Data.DataSetExtensions
- System.Management
- System.Xml
- System.Xml.Linq

I've tried looking for the error value: "**2147942593**" but no luck.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should add the .exe to the Task Scheduler, not the DLL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error code 2147942593 (hex 0x800700C1) is the [HRESULT encapsulation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg567305.aspx) of Windows error code C1, or `ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT`.

(search for 0xC1 in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx)

In a task scheduler this often occurs in one of the following cases:

1. The path points to a file that isn't an EXE program.  If you literally entered the path to a DLL, this could be the cause.
2. The path includes spaces and isn't quoted.  See [Why "schtasks" does not run my job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845030/why-schtasks-does-not-run-my-job)

Comment: Thanks for replying! 
The path points to an ".exe" and it tries to launch it, since the error is in reference to a .dll that's referenced in the .exe. I'm going to try and check other information with "ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT" this might be interesting: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782541(v=ws.10).aspx Thank you!