# How to escape schtasks /tr arguments

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I need to schedule a PowerShell task like following:

```
powershell.exe -file ..\Execute\execute.ps1
```

And I have tried assigning it to an argument `$Argument` then pass it to `schtasks` like following:

```
$Argument = "powershell.exe -file '..\Execute\execute.ps1'"
schtasks /create /tn "SOE_Checks" /tr $Argument /sc DAILY /st 05:00 /ru "System" /rl HIGHEST /f
```

but after running above code, nothing happened - while the task is created successfully, it appears not to run.

I have also tried assigning it to `$Argument` without the quotes, it worked but I got the following warnings:

```
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Value expected for '/tr'.
Type "SCHTASKS /CREATE /?" for usage.
```

Can anyone please let me know what I have done wrong here? (I am aware that I can accomplish this using PowerShell's `New-ScheduledTaskAction` but I want it to work this way)

Just want to add that if I change the file path to a specific location in `$Argument` like this, 
`$Argument = "powershell.exe -file 'C:\SOE\Execute\execute.ps1'"`, it works fine without any warnings but this is not ideal.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845030/why-schtasks-does-not-run-my-job/3845970) but it does not work for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scheduled tasks created with `schtasks.exe` execute with the **working directory set to `$env:windir\system32`**<sup>[1]</sup>, so unless your script happens to be located in `..\Execute\execute.ps1` relative to *there*, your command won't work as intended.

If you don't want to hard-code the script path directly into the command, **construct the command *dynamically*, by resolving the relative path to an *absolute* one when you assign to `$Argument`**:

```
$Argument = 'powershell.exe -file \"{0}\"' -f (Convert-Path ..\Execute\execute.ps1)
```

<sup>Note the - unfortunate - need to escape the embedded `"` as `\"`, which is longstanding bug that hasn't been fixed for the sake of backward compatibility - see [this GitHub docs issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/2361) for background.</sup>

`Convert-Path` resolves a relative path to an absolute one.
Note that the relative path must refer to an existing file (or directory).

Similarly, **relative paths *inside* your script** will be **relative to `$env:windir\system32` too**; to **make them relative to the *script*'s directory**, change to your script's directory first by executing **`Set-Location $PSScriptRoot`** at the start of your script.

---

#### Optional reading: How to quote commands that run from a scheduled task:

Note: Virtually the **same rules** apply as when **running a command from the Windows Run dialog** (press <kbd>WinKey+R</kbd>), which **you can use to *test-drive* a command** (the command to pass to `schtasks /tr`, without outer quoting, not the whole `schtasks` command line) - though note that the working directory will be the user's home directory, and that you won't be able to use `'...'`-quoting around the PowerShell CLI's `-File` argument - see below):

- **`cmd.exe` is NOT involved** during execution, which means:

  - You needn't worry about non-double-quoted use of `cmd.exe` metacharacters such as `&`, for instance, so you can use these characters even in *single*-quoted strings passed to the PowerShell CLI `powershell.exe` as (part of) the `-Command` argument(s).
  - Conversely, output redirections (e.g., `> c:\path\to\log.txt`) are *not directly* supported.
  - In the context of invoking the PowerShell CLI, this means:

    - With `-File`, you cannot use them on the command line and must instead perform them from *within* your script.
    - With `-Command`, however, you *can* use them, because it is then *PowerShell* that applies them (but note that Windows PowerShell's `>` operator creates UTF-16LE files).
- (Even though `cmd.exe` *isn't* involved) **references to *environment variables* using the same syntax form as in `cmd.exe` *are* expanded** (e.g., `%USERNAME%`)

  - **Caveat**: You ***cannot escape* such references**:
  - `%%` doesn't work - the additional `%` is simply treated as a literal, and expansion still occurs; e.g., `%%OS%%` results in `%Windows_NT%`.
  - `^%` (accidentally) prevents expansion, but *retains the `^`* - the `^` doesn't *escape*; rather, it "disrupts" the variable name, in which case the token is left as-is; e.g., `^%OS^%` results in `^%OS^%`, i.e., is retained as-is.

The above applies to the commands as they must *end up* defined inside a scheduled task, as you would see or define them interactively in Task Scheduler (`taskschd.msc`).

**Additionally**, for creating a scheduled task **from the command line / a PowerShell script / a batch file**:

- you must **quote the command *as a whole*** and
- comply with the syntax rules of the calling shell regarding escaping and up-front string interpolation.

(You can only get away *without* quoting if the command consists of only a *single word* that needs no escaping, such the path to an executable that contains no spaces or special characters and to which no arguments are passed.)

When calling `schtasks.exe`<sup>[2]</sup>, **quote the `/tr` argument as a whole as follows**:

- **from PowerShell**, use `"..."`, if you need to expand (string-interpolate) the command string *up front*; otherwise, use `'...'`.
  **Important**: The need to escape *nested* `"` as `\"` applies in both cases, which in the case of outer `"..."` quoting means that nested `"` must be escaped as `` \`" `` (sic).

  - Surprisingly, **`schtasks.exe` recognizes *embedded* `'...'` quoting and automatically translates it to `"..."` quoting** - that is why your original command, `"powershell.exe -file '..\Execute\execute.ps1'"`, worked, even though in *direct* invocation the PowerShell CLI does *not* support the use of `'...'` in combination with `-File`.
- **from `cmd.exe`** (whether directly or from a batch file), you *must* use `"..."`.

**PowerShell examples**:

- The following PowerShell commands create and execute two run-once 
  scheduled tasks,  named `test1` and `test2`, that run when the next calendar minute starts, in the context of the calling user, visibly. (You'll have to remove these tasks manually afterwards.)
- You may have to wait for up to 1 minute to see the invocation kick in, at which point a new console window pops up for each task.

```
# Create sample script test.ps1 in the current dir. that
# echoes its arguments and then waits for a keypress.
'"Hi, $Args."; Read-Host "Press ENTER to exit"' > test.ps1

# Find the start of the next calendar minute.
$nextFullMinute = ([datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(1).TimeOfDay.ToString('hh\:mm'))

# -File example:
# Invoke test.ps1 and pass it 'foo' as an argument.
# Note the escaped embedded "..." quoting around the script path
# and that with -File you can only pass literal arguments at 
# invocation time).
schtasks.exe /create /f /tn test1 /sc once /st $nextFullMinute `
  /tr "powershell -File \`"$PWD/test.ps1\`" foo"                                                                            #`# (dummy comment to fix broken syntax highlighting)

# -Command example:
# Invoke test.ps1 and pass it $env:USERNAME as an argument.
# Note the '...' around the script path and the need to invoke it with
# &, as well as the ` before $env:USERNAME to prevent its premature expansion.
schtasks.exe /create /f /tn test2 /sc once /st $nextFullMinute `
  /tr "powershell -Command & '$PWD/test.ps1' `$env:USERNAME"

"Tasks will execute at ${nextFullMinute}:00"
```

---

<sup>[1] Note that the Task Scheduler GUI allows you to configure a working directory, but this feature isn't available via the `schtasks.exe` utility.</sup>

<sup>[2] The same applies to values passed to the `-Argument` parameter of the `New-ScheduledTaskAction` PowerShell cmdlet, though note that the executable name/path is specified separately there, via the `-Execute` parameter.

By contrast, the `Register-ScheduledJob` cmdlet for creating scheduled PowerShell *jobs* accepts a *script block* as the command to run, which eliminates the quoting headaches.</sup>

Comment: Additionally, to address their issue, they need to embed the quotes to their command `$arg = '"powershell -file '...'"'; ... /TR $arg`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: While that doesn't hurt, it isn't necessary -  not even with filenames with embedded spaces and cmd.exe metacharacters, such as `&` (cmd.exe isn't involved in the invocation).
Please see my update.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work for me but if I change the code to `$Argument = powershell.exe -file "..\Execute\execute.ps1"` (only quote the relative path) then it works perfectly but I don't know why. Would you be able to explain it? 

I will choose yours as the answer anyway cause I learned a lot from it and also I will post an answer that worked for me just in case :)

Thank you

Comment: Thanks, @JiaHao - but your command _instantly executes_ your script, which is not what you want. As for the solution in this answer: check the value of `$Argument` after the assignment and see if contains the correct full path to the script.